# How to track screentime of Java apps with Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, java, parental-controls, screen-time

I am using macOS screen time as a mechanism for parental controls. Before updating to Catalina, the screen time tracked the total time a user was logged in with his/her credentials, regardless of what apps they used or games were played. After the update, it tracks some individual apps.

The problem is that screen time is not tracking for example the time used for java apps. E.g with Minecraft, only the Minecraft launcher is tracked but not the game itself which runs java.

Is there any way to enable the screen time to track the usage of the java apps and/or total login time? Total logged-in time matches with Finder usage time, but open can not add Finder to the list of tracked apps.

The question is, is it possible to add java or Finder to the list of the apps tracked by screen time?

An alternative solution may be third-party software, but those I haven't yet looked for.

Comment: As an afterthought, one possibility could be to write a script which would periodically check if the allowed time for Finder is overrun or not. And if yes, prevent certain programs on running.  Is there any way for a script to get this information?

Comment: Re third party software, Rescue Time is excellent and has a decent free tier, but I don't use any Java apps so I don't know whether or not it will track them correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Even if macOS can’t track Minecraft (since it doesn't track the general class of Java apps and applets), there are tools designed to manage Minecraft.

[This collection of shell scripts](https://github.com/soferio/minertimer) was designed for precisely this problem - managing Minecraft. I created it to stop someone burning up more than 30 minutes per day on Minecraft.

Comment: This could be an excellent option. I do wonder if you could put a license on the scripts so that people know if they can legally make a copy to their computer to test or change the timeout value if they keep it on their computer. [The default on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/licensing-a-repository) is that no one can reproduce, modify or copy the code. The WTFPL and MIT license might work well for your tool after browsing the scripts. Nice work and thanks for sharing here!

Comment: I have added the MIT licence.

Comment: Wow - that's great - thanks so much again

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this StackOverflow thread where they instruct on how to package the jars into an .app for Mac, that might do the trick:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037693/convert-java-application-to-mac-os-x-app